# Insertar En mongodb con php

Tags: php, mongodb

Tengo un index en php de esta forma, recorte algunos campos para no hacer largo esto

```
<form method="post" id="formu" >
     <div class="holo"> <input type="text" name="Nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required="required" 
      /></div>

      <div class="holo">  <input type="text" name="Cargo" id="Cargo" placeholder="Cargo" required="required" 
     /></div>

       <div class="holo"> <input type="text" name="Correo" id="Correo" placeholder="Correo" required="required" 
        /></div>

      <div class="holo">  <input type="text" name="Extension" id="Extension" placeholder="Extension" required="required"
   /></div> </form>
```

Y la operacion  de insertar que estoy haciendo es esta

```
 <?php 

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use MongoDB\Client as Mongo;
        $mongo = new Mongo();

        //$mongo = new Mongo();
        $db = $mongo->Directorio;
        //$db = $mongo->selectDB("librosdb");

        $c_autores = $mongo->selectCollection($db,"Coordinacione");


       if($_POST){
        $insert= array(
    'nombre' => $_POST['Nombre'],
    'cargo' => $_POST['Cargo'],
    'correo' => $_POST['Correo'],
    'extension' => $_POST['Extension'],
    'piso' => $_POST['Piso'],
    'edificio' => $_POST['Edificio']
        );


     }

    $c_autores->insert($insert);


    ?>
```

Pero al cargar la pagina me marca error en el insertar, no se si tenga mal o alguien podria explicar detalladamente como insertar

Comment: Qué error te marca? Soy nuevo en PHP, pero veo que en Nombre el id='nombre', pero en el $_POST lo pones como 'Nombre'. Tal vez tenga algo que ver...

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Collection::insert() in C:\xampp\htdocs\directorio\conexionusuario.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\directorio\vistas\crearusuario.php(2): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\directorio\conexionusuario.php on line 29

Comment: El error dice que no tienes un método llamado insert()